# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, page-factory

I was trying to run my old selenium practiced scripts which were working fine a month ago and are throwing  errors now, especially at the constructor

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Any advice?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;

public class LoginPage extends TestBase {
    
    @FindBy(name="username")`enter code here`
    WebElement Username;

    @FindBy(name="password")
    WebElement Password;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='input-group-btn']//input")
    WebElement LoginBtn;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")
    WebElement SignUPLink;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='navbar-brand']//img")
    WebElement CRMPROLogo;
    
    public  LoginPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    //#Actions
    public String ValidateLoginPageTitle() {
         return driver.getTitle();
    }
    public boolean ValidateCRMlogoImg() {
        return CRMPROLogo.isEnabled();
    }
    public  HomePage ValidateLoginTest(String un, String pwd) throws InterruptedException {
        Username.sendKeys(un);
        Password.sendKeys(pwd);
        LoginBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return new HomePage();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod SetUp
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Object)'
    at com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPage.<init>(LoginPage.java:29)
    at com.crm.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.SetUp(LoginPageTest.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSuchMethodError normally means you compiled with one version, but are running with a different (normally older) version, hence the Exception.

The solution is to make sure you are developing and running on the same version of Java, selenium, and any other 3rd party library you are also using

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The issue was resolved when I downgraded my selenium version in maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-added the selenium jar file and TestNG library, and it's working!

Work around: Project name > right click > Build path > Configure Build Path... > Add External Library(to add selenium jar file) and > Add Library (to add TestNG)